# I am stuck - I keep getting - > module 'scipy' has no attribute '__version__'?

Tags: scipy, attributes

I am wondering why this keeps happening module 'scipy' has no attribute `'__version__'`? I am a newbie to Python.

When I did what the first comment asked me to do I get :
 In [430]: import scipy SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import scipy                                                                                 
>>> scipy.__version__                                                                            
'1.4.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - so when I did that I received --> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry -  so when I did that I received --> In [430]: import scipy SyntaxError: invalid syntax